# Why Console.log printing "Unrecognized event:..." in Expo React native app

Tags: react-native, printing, expo, visual-studio-debugging, console.log

When I am printing any value in my react native app console:-

for e.g.:-   `console.log('Printing Data')`

Then it's printing data twice as follows:-

```
Unrecognized event: {"type":"client_log","level":"log","data":["Printing Data"]}
Printing Data
```

How can I prevent printing of "Unrecognized event: {..." ?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happens, try to update EXPO CLI

```
npm install -g expo-cli.
```